# Converting distinct values of column into individual column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to two tables

Table1 contains

```
empID,
```

Table 2 contains

```
procedure code 
procedure date 
common column
```

between these two tables is procedure code.

procedure date is in format yyyy-mm-dd year-month column is to be derived from procedure date as left(4,7) as year-month.

procedure code column contains different procedure code which needs to be converted into new individual columns as pro-1, pro-2, pro-3 as given below in table output.

Table output should be number or sum of procedure coming into columns pro-1,pro-2,pro-2 for each id in each year-month.

I need table in a format like given below

```
empID, year-month, pro-1, pro-2, pro-3 , pro 4

1       jan-2016    3000   4000  5000     6000
1       feb-2016    1500   2000  600      8000
2        jan 2016   4000   5000  7000     900
```

Here row 1 means for empid 1 in jan 2016 sum of pro-1 is 3000

Comment: how do the input tables look like? and how do you get 3000 under `pro-1`?

Comment: 3000 is number of procedures given by empId-1 in Jan2016

Comment: how do you join tab1 and tab2? there's no common field based on your question. Could you please update your question to add sample rows from the input tables and add all calculations that you want and might have tried?

Comment: Actaully procedure code is common column between two tables and that is where my doubt is how shall I join two tables and convert unique values of procedure code into individual columns or shall I create new table instead of joining I'm not able to understand

Comment: please add such details to the question body.

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: "procedure code ... which needs to be converted"   How do you think this conversion should be done, when you do not share information about it?